# css сделать картинку по высоте

Tags: html, css

Есть код

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content"><img src="http://game.webfather.ru/img.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы картинка по высоте экрана была? Сейчас она выше высоту даже, если прописать `max-height:100%;`, есть вариант прописать `position:absolute;`, но мне это не подходит, так как ломается верстка на сайте полностью из-за этого.

Подскажите, какие есть варианты сделать картинку при таком наборе элементов не больше высоты экрана?

Comment: поправил ваш код. используйте встроеный редактор для выкладывания кода, ибо иначе он интерпретируется в то, что вы видели

Comment: для этого нужна будет картинка не всякая , а такая что бы пропорционально могла тянутся , вообще для изображения стили такие  display:block; width:100%;  а высоту не указываем так как высота подстроится автоматом , дальше для родителя те же  параметры  - вот пример на fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bq6zhta1/

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content img {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://yandex.ru/images/today?size=1920x1080" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно наоборот прописать `min-width: 100%; height: 100%;`

Остается только выровнять картинку по горизонтали (если её исходная ширина известна, это не составит проблем).